# HTML file input doesn't show gallery on android just show document option

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

HTML file input gallery doesn't show while select any file using android mobile, i'm not able to understand how to fix it but i tried it

```
<input type="file" ca  accept="image/*"/>
```

but doesn't work on android someone have any idea?

Comment: This works on my phone. Which phone and browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Samsung galaxy J7

Comment: Does the phone show any options if you click on the input element?

Comment: Yes just show "Document" and "Camera" options by the way we can reach to gallery by "Document" option but requirement is when click on input then gallery should open directly.

Comment: I've tested this on several phones with the standard browser, Chrome and [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) yesterday and it seems that only [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) does support the gallery option.